# Peek messages does not work on Azure Service Bus Topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to peek messages from Service Bus Topic on Azure Service Bus portal without luck, getting the following error

[image]

[image]

Works for subscription (when you select one) but not for topic

Comment: Have you checked this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/explorer)?@user3543878

Comment: After going into the service bus topic blade, I can be able to select the corresponding service bus subscription and peek the messages as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/ghlBtRO.png). Is this the one you are mentioning about? @user3543878

Comment: Yes @Jahnavi that's the one I am talking about but without selecting any subscription in the dropdownlist just newt in your screenshot, it works when you select one but not on the topic (newt) itself. Peek from start and Peek next messages is throwing that error (works for Dead-letter), hope it makes sense.

Comment: Without selecting a subscription, you will be able to send messages but peek from start will not work as expected without selecting a subscription as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/g77k34V.png). @user3543878

Comment: @Jahnavi send messages is different, should select Peek Mode for Peek from start and Peek next messages to work, peek works on another topic but not the one which I am after

Comment: As it is working for other topics, this might be a transient problem which should clear automatically after some time. Did you try refreshing the portal and peek again? @user3543878

Comment: @Jahnavi yup tried everything multiple times without luck, btw that topic is on different environment

Comment: Which environment it is? @user3543878

Comment: @Jahnavi test environment, works on one test environment but not on other

Comment: Have you tried with PowerShell or any other? @user3543878

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255742/discussion-between-user3543878-and-jahnavi).

Comment: Peeking messages on a topic is not an officially supported operation; peek would need to be performed on a subscription.   If this is allowed at all in the portal, it's a bug and works by coincidence, not by design.   I've brought this to the attention of the folks that own the portal experience.

Comment: @JesseSquire my understanding is that peeking messages on the topic returns Scheduled messages whereas peeking on a subscription returns Active/Dead-letter messages based on the selection.

Comment: To be clear - peeking of messages on a topic is not supported and should not be relied upon for a production application.  However, in some contexts it does work to expose scheduled messages because the service rules don't validate an edge case and treats it like you're querying a queue.  The important take-away is that we intentionally do not document this nor offer support.   As an official tool, the portal should be preventing this.

Comment: Oh okay, so what's the best way out to transfer scheduled messages from one service bus to another service bus @JesseSquire

Comment: If you're looking to do so before they come due, you'd want to cancel the message using the sequence number returned when it was scheduled and send that data to the desired resource.

Comment: I would like to keep the scheduled messages as it is on the source service bus, neither cancel nor delete and transfer the same scheduled messages to the new service bus (target), is there any other way to achieve the above apart from peek messages @JesseSquire

Comment: Service Bus isn't intended to be a database; when messages are scheduled, the intent is to allow them to be delivered/acted at the time they were scheduled for.  Treating scheduled messages as a data source is not a design that I'd recommend, and isn't something that I can think of a reasonable workflow for.

Comment: Okay, how do I acheive this "cancel the message using the sequence number returned...", tried retrieving messages including MeesageReceiver without luck getting the same error as I mentioned above @JesseSquire

Comment: When you schedule a message, its sequence number is returned.   You'll use that with the sender's `CancelScheduledMessageAsync` method:  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussender.cancelscheduledmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: I am talking about the scheduled messages which are already on Service Bus @JesseSquire

Comment: There is not a supported way, as this is not how scheduled messages are intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary issue that could occur in Azure services. As it works for other service bus topics, this could not stay long, and it will resolve itself after some time.

*Need to check below:*

- Try refreshing the portal or try running in different browser and peek messages once again.
- It could be a problem with the server connectivity of that specific service bus topic. Clear your browser cache and sign in again into the portal.
- Aside from the Azure Portal, you may utilize `Azure SDK's` such as `Python` and `Java` to automate the processing of scheduled messages. As you already mentioned, the same error was throwing even tried with the console app, make sure you're using the most recent `Azure SDK` to avoid conflicts.
- And also check whether the service bus namespace has necessary permissions to schedule and send the messages. Go to
  `Access control` of service bus topic and then add a suitable role assignment as shown.

[image]

By referring to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/explorer), I understood that selecting a subscription inside the topic and then send messages in peek mode would be an efficient way instead of doing it only from the topic.

[image]

[image]

*If still the issue persists, I would recommend you raise a support request that helps to resolve the server issue quickly.*

Comment: As discussed above, peeking messages on a topic is not a supported operation.  Even if it were, the content of this answer is generic and does not address the question being asked.

Comment: It was already discussed in the comments section and had given the answer to check the above points related to the internal server error. @Jesse Squire